# Watin:Refering to href attribute of anchor tag under List item Tag

Tags: watin, anchor, href

I am new to Watin Testing Tool. I am trying to automate my application.
 But i am not able to find the Input Element ie anchor tag having href attribute
  .Anchor tag is under List item which is under div tag.

Please help

Comment: Could you add the code you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have severall options:

```
var link = browser.Link(Find.ByUrl("http://needs.to.be/exact/match.url"));
```

or

```
var link = browser.Link(Find.ByUrl(url => url != null && url.Contains("partial/match.url"));
```

or I you want to find a url specifically inside a list item (as of WatiN 2.0.50):

```
var link = browser.ListItem("listItemIdHere").Link(Find.ByUrl(url => url != null && url.Contains("partial/match.url"));
```

Comment: I tried wid above code but i am getting invalid URI Error.<a href="Home"> is the code which i am trying to automate. Please Help

Comment: Have you tried the second option (using a lambda expression) as well? That should work in your case.